# Return two decimal places value for the variable extracted from php code for Google Trusted Store

Tags: php, magento

Below is my code for Google trusted Store. Currently it generates numeric values with four decimal places. For example, the value for this code: getGrandTotal(); ?>
it returns value in the format 25.0000 Is there a way it could be forced to return a value for 2 decimal places i.e 25.00

Thanks,

```
<?php
     $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
     $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
     $backorder = false; // some backorder logic
     $download = false; // some download logic
     $shipDate = new Zend_Date(); // some logic to determine ship date
?>

<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">


    <span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-domain">www.example.com</span>
    <span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-country"><?php echo htmlentities($address->getCountryId()); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>
    <span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo $shipDate->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><?php echo $backorder ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-digital"><?php echo $download ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>     

    <?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
          <span class="gts-item">
          <span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
        </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


</div>
```

Comment: try `number_format()` or `money_format()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `number_format` function of PHP. For example,

```
<?php
$number = 25.0000;
echo number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', ''); 
?>
```

This will print

> 25.00

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code as following to achieve the objective

```
<?php echo(round($order->getGrandTotal(),2)); ?>
```